# Perforce equivalent to svn switch

Tags: svn, version-control, perforce

In svn/cvs I often created a local checkout of main/trunk to start working in the code, and then, when real commit branch is ready, switch to it and start commiting the code there.

I am aware Perforce have quite a different workflow, but I wonder if there is any way to perform a switch and have the local code start pointing to a different branch in the remote repository than before.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Essentially:

- Shelve your local changes
- Update workspace view to point to the other branch
- Run `p4 sync` to update your working copy
- Unshelve your work in progress

Several parts of that are better in the 2011.1 release:

- There's a new `p4 update` command that does a fast workspace update for in-place branching
- If you use streams, you there's a one-step way to move your workspace to a new stream

Perforce has a new P4Sandbox tool out in a limited beta right now.  That tool is for private local work, and it does have a `p4 switch` command that will feel very familiar to you.

Comment: Sadly, my version of perforce does not support shelves. I read a bit about the sandbox tool and it looks very promising, I hope we will be able to use it!